# Manage tomcat logging from webapp

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, catalina.out

Is there some way to manage tomcat logging from the log4j xml of a webapp ?

By this , I mean I am specifically looking to stop logs of level SEVERE from WebappClassLoader from being put into the catalina.out log.

EDIT :

While researching, I came to know that log4j will give priority to  log4j.xml from any parent class loader if the file is present or the one present in WEB-INF/classes. If no other log4j.xml file is present for parent class loaders , will the default setting be taken for tomcat and application specific from the webapp log4j.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think there's no way to override Tomcat's logging settings in a web application.

To solve your problem you may try to change [Tomcat's default logging configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_%28default%29). If you prefer log4j, you may try [to configure Tomcat to use log4j](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j) instead of java.util.logging.